# Maintaining Edit History while editing from userform VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a userform which is used for both submitting entries and editing them if needed. I am auto populating the form if a person enters a unique id (Material verification checklist number) with the help of TextBox After Update function

Then the user can change any parameters and press edit button to edit the changes. All these things work fine.

There is a requirement to maintain the edit history of all the changes in a different sheet. I am stuck there. This is how the sheet will look:

[image]

I am stuck with the C, D and E columns which should capture what parameters were edited, and their old and new values.

This is my code for the edit function right now:

```
Sub Edit()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
    Dim id As Range
    Set id = Worksheets("Transport Assesment").Range("A:A").Find(what:=frm3.TextBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    
    Worksheets("Transport Assesment").Unprotect "Ramu@lt12"
    
    id.Offset(, 1).Value = frm3.TextBox13.Value
    id.Offset(, 2).Value = frm3.DTPicker2.Value
    id.Offset(, 4).Value = frm3.ComboBox7.Value
    id.Offset(, 3).Value = frm3.ComboBox8.Value
    id.Offset(, 5).Value = frm3.ComboBox6.Value
    id.Offset(, 25).Value = frm3.TextBox15.Value
    id.Offset(, 6).Value = frm3.ComboBox1.Value
    id.Offset(, 7).Value = frm3.TextBox2.Value
    id.Offset(, 8).Value = frm3.ComboBox2.Value
    id.Offset(, 9).Value = frm3.TextBox3.Value
    id.Offset(, 10).Value = frm3.ComboBox3.Value
    id.Offset(, 11).Value = frm3.TextBox4.Value
    id.Offset(, 12).Value = frm3.ComboBox4.Value
    id.Offset(, 13).Value = frm3.TextBox5.Value
    id.Offset(, 14).Value = frm3.ComboBox5.Value
    id.Offset(, 15).Value = frm3.TextBox6.Value
    id.Offset(, 16).Value = frm3.DTPicker3.Value
    id.Offset(, 17).Value = frm3.TextBox14.Value
    id.Offset(, 18).Value = frm3.DTPicker4.Value
    id.Offset(, 19).Value = frm3.TextBox9.Value
    id.Offset(, 20).Value = frm3.DTPicker1.Value
    id.Offset(, 26).Value = frm3.TextBox16.Value
    
    Worksheets("Transport Assesment").Protect "Ramu@lt12"
    
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Please guide me on how should I capture the parameters changed, and their old and new values. Thanks

Comment: Do you have to capture all column (listed in your code) in the edit history? or can you do with a subset of these columns?

Comment: I have to capture the columns which were edited, so if A and  B parameters were edited, the C column should show A ; B, and old values should show old values of A and B seperated by ;

Comment: For each cell you update, check to see if the existing value is different from the "new" value - if it is then add the name, old and new values to each of three strings you use to track these items.  When done updating the edited row, add a line to your tracking sheet.

Comment: I understood your logic and it should work well, but I am not sure how to record the parameter, old and new values in different strings if the old and new values are different. I am very new to vba, I am sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest using a separate sub to handle comparing the values and updating the tracking info where there's a difference:

```vb
'globals for tracking any changes
Dim oldValues, newValues, titles

Sub Edit()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
    Dim id As Range
    
    oldValues = ""
    newValues = ""
    titles = ""
    
    Set id = Worksheets("Transport Assesment").Range("A:A").Find( _
                    what:=frm3.TextBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    
    If Not id Is Nothing Then
    
        Worksheets("Transport Assesment").Unprotect "Ramu@lt12"
        
        LogChanges id.Offset(, 1), frm3.TextBox13.Value
        LogChanges id.Offset(, 2), frm3.DTPicker2.Value
        LogChanges id.Offset(, 4), frm3.ComboBox7.Value
        LogChanges id.Offset(, 3), frm3.ComboBox8.Value
        LogChanges id.Offset(, 5), frm3.ComboBox6.Value
        'etc etc for rest of cells
        
        If Len(titles) > 0 Then
            'have changes - update the tracking sheet
        End If
        
        Worksheets("Transport Assesment").Protect "Ramu@lt12"
    Else
        MsgBox "No match found!"
    End If
    
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub

'compare form value with existing: log any change and update cell if required
Sub LogChanges(c As Range, vNew)
    With c
        sep = IIf(Len(titles) > 0, ";", "") 'need a separator?
        If .Value <> vNew Then
            'track the changes
            titles = titles & sep & .Parent.Cells(1, .Column).Value 'column titles in Row1
            oldValues = oldValues & sep & ValueOrBlank(.Value)  'track old value
            newValues = newValues & sep & ValueOrBlank(vNew)    'track new value
            .Value = vNew                                       'update the cell
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Function ValueOrBlank(v)
    ValueOrBlank = IIf(Len(v)>0, v, "[blank]")
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out, it solved the problem